# How to mount one engine in another mountable engine in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently there are two engines mounted in main application in config/routes.rb as follows.

mount firstEngine::Engine, at: '/search' and 
mount secondEngine::Engine, at: '/add'

I want to move mounting of firstEngine from application to secondEngine. In other words how to mount one engine in another mountable engine? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have been also trying to mount one engine on top of another, this is what I got so far:

```
#file myapp/config/routes.rb
mount Bar::Engine => "/bar"

#file myapp/Gemfile
gem 'bar', :path => '../bar'
```

Project structure is like this:

my_project_folder
|
+-- myapp
|
+-- bar
|
+-- baz

```
#file bar/config/routes
mount Baz::Engine => '/baz'
```

I ran into trouble mounting Baz on top of Bar, simply adding

```
#file bar/Gemfile
gem: 'baz', :path => '../baz'
```

did not work, I got uninitialized constant Baz::Engine error

Solved it like this:

```
#file bar/lib/engine.rb
require File.join(File.expand_path('../../../baz/lib', File.dirname(__FILE__)), 'baz')
```

Now baz.rb is complaining: cannot load such file -- baz/engine
So I changed:

```
#file baz/lib/baz.rb
require_relative './baz/engine' # instead of require 'baz/engine'
```

Now my /bar/baz route is working.
It is rather ugly workaround and I will be looking for cleaner solution but both my mountable plugins are under development and I use them only from source so I do not mind for the moment. Hope it helped at least a bit. Please let me know if you find a better solution.